# Can't create an executable jar with all dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I want to create an executable jar with all dependencies so that I can deploy it later on AWS.

I tried out several different methods. They all produce a jar file, but executing it yields nothing (see below).

The first method involved using IntelliJ. I did the following: File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Added jar -> Selected Main Class -> Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build.
Afterwards, I executed the created JAR. I received the following error: `no main manifest attribute, in benchmark.JAR`.

So I decided to add the MANIFEST.MF manually:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Benchmark
Class-Path: .
```

...and built the JAR using IntelliJ. I ended up having about 30 different jars. After I have executed benchmark.JAR, I got: `CP:/Users/.../benchmark.jar`.

I decided to try something else, namely the maven-jar-plugin.
I added the following configuration to the pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>Benchmark</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This didn't work either. I executed `jar:jar` and found the following error:
`Error: Unable to initialize main class Benchmark Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory`

Undismayed I tried another option which is the spring-boot-maven-plugin:
Please note: my project is **not** a spring-boot project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                <mainClass>Benchmark</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I executed *clean*, *install*, and *repackage*. I obtained the JAR, executed it, received: `CP:benchmark.jar.`

Then came the turn for the maven-shade-plugin. I executed shade, package+shade, package - unfortunately to no avail. I have: `CP:benchmark.jar%`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation=
                                            "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>Benchmark</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

According to the comment, I also tried with the maven-assemble-plugin. It doesn't work either. It gives me: CP:benchmark.jar

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    Benchmark
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Try this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: This doesn't work either. Similarly to the other method, I get: CP:benchmark.jar, and nothing happens. I'll edit the original post with the config of this plugin.

Comment: If you have a spring boot project you should use spring-boot-maven-plugin nothing else...that does everything which is needed ....

Comment: It is not. I edited the post, to extend the info.

Comment: It would be much easier to help with your problem if you could share a small sample project to reproduce this issue on GitHub, just one class and one dependency used in this class should probably be enough.

Comment: You should use maven-shade-plugin to create such thing. The main class you have defined is without a package which means the default package that is wrong. Create a package where you should move your main class to...

Comment: The project structure is:
src -> main -> java, and in the java directory I have some packages and the main class:
package1
package2
package3
Main
@CrazyCoder: I will modify my project a lil bit, and I will post a link to git in an hour.